# Background Image on Cover Page Distorted in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to incorporate the following image into the cover page of my report.
It's currently saved as a PNG file with dimension 1275 x 1650.

[image]

Like a lot of online posts suggested, I

```
*   inserted a rectangle
*   set the image as the background image
```

And here are my properties for the rectangle.

[image]

When I rendered my report to PDF, the image was splitted 
into multiple blank pages and the bottom of the graphic (with logo and URL)
didn't even show.

How can I make sure this graphic is displayed fully on only the first page?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you have other objects on your cover page, but here's what I did to get this working correctly.

1. Add an image object to your report.
2. Make sure the margins are set fairly low(I used .25in for top, bottom, left, and right).
3. With the margins set at .25in, I set the image object to a size of 8in x 10.5in to fill the remaining space on the page.
4. In the image object properties, set padding options all to zero and Display to "Fit to size".

Now the trick here, is to put the image object in the very top left corner and resize the report to the exact size of the image object -- no whitespace in the design view.  For me, this returns a single page report with the entire image shown on a single page.